# Do I need to make a variable for values and keys in dictionaries if I just want input to be keys and to count up 1 for every user input

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

```
def get_animals():
    animals_dict=dict()

    max_length = 3

    while len(animals_dict) < max_length:
        animals = input("enter an animal:")

        if animals not in animals_dict:

print(animals_dict)
```

here is my code so far, I am trying to get user input for different animals, and if the animal is not in the dictionary for it to count up to 1 every time. Do I need

```
animals_dict[animals] = name
```

under my if statement?

I'll put my assignment below in case I did a bad job explaining it.

> Dictionary Update Assignment Write a program that prompts the user for
> animals, stores them in a dictionary as keys, and the corresponding
> value keeps a count of how many times that animal has been entered.
> Write a function get_animals() Create an empty dictionary animals_dict
> = dict() Write a loop that prompts the user for an animal (string) If that animal exists as a key in the dictionary, add 1 to the
> corresponding value If that animal does not exist as a key in the
> dictionary, update the dictionary to add it as a key and set the value
> to 1 Write a second function most_seen_animal() that accepts the
> dictionary as the only parameter and returns the animal with the
> highest number of occurrences. Note a dictionary is a set of key, and
> value pairs. You can get the keys with keys() function You can access
> the value using a key variable animals_dict.get(k) What about testing?
> Write a main to test your functions Unit Tests can also help test
> most_seen_animal()

Answer (score 1):

You need a dictionary where the key is the animal and the value is the count. You can initialize an unseen animal by doing `animals_dict[animals] = 0` then adding the counter every loop:

```
def get_animals():
    animals_dict=dict()

    max_length = 3

    while len(animals_dict) < max_length:
        animals = input("enter an animal:")

        if animals not in animals_dict:
           animals_dict[animals] = 0
        
        animals_dict[animals] += 1
   
    return animals_dict
```

Or you can use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_animals():
    animals_dict= defaultdict(int)

    max_length = 3

    while len(animals_dict) < max_length:
        animals = input("enter an animal:")
        animals_dict[animals] += 1
    
    return animals_dict
```

Also, considering your input is asking for a singular animal, you should rename the variable `animals` to `animal`

```
animal = input("enter an animal:")
```

Then, you should give more context to what the dictionary is holding (and ditch the _dict keyword, you should already know its a dictionary)

```
animals_counter = defaultdict(int)
```